# rdp connecting problem occured

Tags: xrdp, rdp

My problem below

Connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait...
login failed for display 0
If I click Ok the it takes me back to the login dialog.

If I select Xvnc and some credentials then I get a blank green screen.